# AG-Grid SSRM: Sending Multiple Server Requests When Loading Second Last Page

Tags: angular, ag-grid, ag-grid-angular

I'm facing an issue where if the user tries to go to the second last page directly, the network tab on inspect mode shows a lot of server requests being made to load that page data.

Steps to Reproduce

1. User loaded the grid which shows the first page correctly
2. User goes to the last page which shows data as intended
3. Now if the user wants to go to the second last page, it flooded Server HTTP requests

Basically, it tried to start the offset of the page from start rather than checking it from the last page

**Ag-Grid Version: 29.3.4**

[Plunker to Reproduce](https://plnkr.co/edit/sx8QwMHbDzReS5EH)

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import {
  ColDef,
  GridReadyEvent,
  IServerSideDatasource,
  RowModelType,
} from 'ag-grid-community';
import 'ag-grid-community/styles/ag-grid.css';
import 'ag-grid-community/styles/ag-theme-alpine.css';
import 'ag-grid-enterprise';
import { IOlympicData } from './interfaces';

declare var FakeServer: any;

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `<ag-grid-angular
    style="width: 100%; height: 100%;"
    class="ag-theme-alpine-dark"
    [columnDefs]="columnDefs"
    [defaultColDef]="defaultColDef"
    [rowModelType]="rowModelType"
    [pagination]="true"
    [paginationPageSize]="paginationPageSize"
    [cacheBlockSize]="cacheBlockSize"
    [animateRows]="true"
    [rowData]="rowData"
    (gridReady)="onGridReady($event)"
  ></ag-grid-angular> `,
})
export class AppComponent {
  public columnDefs: ColDef[] = [
    { field: 'id', maxWidth: 75 },
    { field: 'athlete', minWidth: 190 },
    { field: 'age' },
    { field: 'year' },
    { field: 'gold' },
    { field: 'silver' },
    { field: 'bronze' },
  ];
  public defaultColDef: ColDef = {
    flex: 1,
    minWidth: 90,
    resizable: true,
  };
  public rowModelType: RowModelType = 'serverSide';
  public paginationPageSize = 10;
  public cacheBlockSize = 10;
  public rowData!: IOlympicData[];

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

  onGridReady(params: GridReadyEvent<IOlympicData>) {
    this.http
      .get<IOlympicData[]>(
        'https://www.ag-grid.com/example-assets/olympic-winners.json'
      )
      .subscribe((data) => {
        // add id to data
        var idSequence = 1;
        data.forEach(function (item: any) {
          item.id = idSequence++;
        });
        // setup the fake server with entire dataset
        var fakeServer = new FakeServer(data);
        // create datasource with a reference to the fake server
        var datasource = getServerSideDatasource(fakeServer);
        // register the datasource with the grid
        params.api!.setServerSideDatasource(datasource);
      });
  }
}

function getServerSideDatasource(server: any): IServerSideDatasource {
  return {
    getRows: (params) => {
      console.log('[Datasource] - rows requested by grid: ', params.request);
      var response = server.getData(params.request);
      // adding delay to simulate real server call
      setTimeout(function () {
        if (response.success) {
          // call the success callback
          params.success({
            rowData: response.rows,
            rowCount: response.lastRow,
          });
        } else {
          // inform the grid request failed
          params.fail();
        }
      }, 200);
    },
  };
}
```

Comment: This seems to be a BUG on ag-grid side. 
I've checked, and it is reproducible with the latest version 29.3.4, both angular and react.

Comment: Hi Any update I have same issue In Vue!

Comment: You can upgrade or downgrade the version to resolve this issue.